# Both Java and C++ Refuse to Emulate Arrow Keys?

Tags: java, c++, keyboard, simulate

Alright, so. This is driving me absolutely insane. I'm building an application in Java and it requires that the keyboard keys be simulated. Like, I want to fool the entire computer into thinking a key is being pressed. (Don't worry, my intentions are not malicious :P ) The problem is, I was using Java's Robot class to simulate the key presses, and there is a bug that doesn't allow for the arrow keys to be pressed in some applications, for whatever reason.

So I figured I would just make a small C++ program to handle the input simulation and call it from Java. But here's the kicker: The arrow keys *still* do not work for some programs. Like, it just doesn't register. They are the same programs that didn't work for Java, as far as I can tell.

Is there any way at all to simulate arrow key presses throughout all programs, 100% of the time? I'm open to any language at this point.

Here's the C++ program I have so far, if it matters.

```
#define WINVER 0x0500
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    INPUT ip;

    Sleep(2000);

    ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip.ki.wScan = 0;
    ip.ki.time = 0;
    ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    ip.ki.wVk = VK_RIGHT;
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

    Sleep(1000);

    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

    return 0;
}
```

I really hope somebody can help me, because I am out of ideas.

Comment: It may be that they don't use the normal means of receiving keyboard input.   Maybe they use either direct input or some other api for keyboard access.

Comment: I read something about that, but I'm not sure how to get around it if that is the case...

Comment: Possibly emulating a keyboard driver if you reaaally need it badly

Answer (score 2):

If it is important that it works on all apps in Windows, you might have to write a driver that emulates a HID - installing and registering your driver as a keyboard in Windows.
Sounds like a lot of work, but Microsoft has the Windows Driver Kit, and in the Windows Driver Kit Samples Pack there is a few interesting samples you can check out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff554118(v=vs.85).aspx

I assume you only need it working on Windows, due to your C++ program.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. My concern with this method (which I probably should've mentioned) is that I'm distributing this program to other people. I have zero experience with drivers, so would this be easy to give to other people?

Comment: I have never written a driver, but I'm sure that giving it to other people will be the least of you worries.
Writing it should be the worst nightmare, getting it certified (unless you can live with warnings/manual install) might be very hard too ... but maybe it is not impossible? There is a sample so how hard can it be? :)

Comment: I don't think I'll bother then. This is just a small program, no need to mess with drivers. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed do this with C++ using the SendKeys class. As detailed in the article linked [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

`keybd_event()` although **deprecated** is another function that synthesizes  a keypress. The key codes show up on keyloggers as long as that targeted program has focus. Simulating start menu key press is as easy as this -

```
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>

using namespace std; 


int main(){
    cout<<"Standby : Simulating start menu key press \n\n";

    keybd_event(VK_LWIN, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
    keybd_event(VK_LWIN, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

To simulate the arrows keys being pressed up and down, try this:

```
// simulate RIGHT key press 
keybd_event(VK_RIGHT,0,0,0);
keybd_event(VK_RIGHT,0,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);

// simulate LEFT key press 
keybd_event(VK_LEFT,0,0,0);
keybd_event(VK_LEFT,0,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);

// simulate UP key press 
keybd_event(VK_UP,0,0,0);
keybd_event(VK_UP,0,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);

// simulate DOWN key press 
keybd_event(VK_DOWN,0,0,0);
keybd_event(VK_DOWN,0,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
```

keybd_event (deprecated) : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee504289.aspx

keybd_event : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx

Virtual-Key Codes : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it appears to have the same result as my current method. The arrow keys don't work on certain applications.